# Looking for the occurence of backslash in a string - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like the position of the 2nd occurence of a backslash in the following string 'abc\d\e'

Tried to use regexp_instr with no success... Any advise? thank you

```
select regexp_instr('abc\d\e\f','\\',2) -> Not working
select regexp_instr('abc\d\e\f','\\',2) -> Not working
select regexp_instr('abc\d\e\f','\\\\',2) -> result: 0 ??
```

Comment: Just use `instr()`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, instr() is not supported by Redshift.

Comment: @ user14068734 . . . then use `position()`.

Comment: @user14068734 I think the problem is your input string not escaping backslash. If you do `select 'abc\d\e\f'` you'll see what I mean. I tried this in snowflake and it works just fine `select regexp_instr('abc\\d\\e\\f','\\\\',1,2,1)-1` Minus one to account for an extra backslash on the first occurence

Comment: Hi Isildur, yes correct. The issue was interestingly in the input string. So the right syntax is: select regexp_instr(string field, '\\\\', 1, 2) Thanks everyone for your contribution.